# Using generate_series in ecto and passing a value

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I am trying to use *generate_series* in this query to get the number of sales in a time period even with the days that have no sales. I got it working with a hard-coded value but now I need to get all the sales since the contract was created.

What I have so far:

```
 query =
  from(
    c in Contract,
    join: v in Voucher,
    on: v.contract_id == c.id,
    join: s in Sale,
    on: s.voucher_id == v.id and c.id == ^contract_id,
    right_join:
      day in fragment(
        "select generate_series(current_date - interval '60 day', current_date, '1 day')::date AS d"
      ),
    on: day.d == fragment("date(?)", s.date),
    group_by: day.d,
    select: %{
      number_sales: count(s.id),
      total_value: sum(s.value),
      date: day.d
    },
    order_by: [asc: day.d]
  )

Repo.all(query)
|> Enum.map(fn entry -> Map.put(entry, :date, Date.from_erl!(entry.date)) end)
```

With this query I get all the sales in the last 60 days even with the days with no sales.

I now changed the line `generate_series('2018-06-01', current_date, '1 day')` to 
 start at the date the contract was created but I get the following error:

```
[debug] QUERY ERROR source="contracts" db=1.0ms
SELECT count(s2."id"), sum(s2."value"), f3."d" FROM "contracts" AS c0 INNER 
JOIN "vouchers" AS v1 ON v1."contract_id" = v1."id" INNER JOIN "sales" AS s2 
ON (s2."voucher_id" = v1."id") AND (c0."id" = $1) RIGHT OUTER JOIN (select 
generate_series(c0."inserted_at", current_date, '1 day')::date AS d) AS f3 ON 
f3."d" = date(s2."date") GROUP BY f3."d" ORDER BY f3."d" [1]
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42P01 (undefined_table): invalid reference to FROM- 
clause entry for table "c0"
(ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:431: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.execute_and_cache/7
(ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:133: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/5
(ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:37: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/4
(app) lib/app/contracts/contracts.ex:313: App.Contracts.get_sales_day/1
```

Modified code:

```
query =
  from(
   c in Contract,
join: v in Voucher,
on: v.contract_id == c.id,
join: s in Sale,
on: s.voucher_id == v.id and c.id == ^contract_id,
right_join:
  day in fragment(
    "select generate_series(?, current_date, '1 day')::date AS d",
    c.inserted_at
  ),
on: day.d == fragment("date(?)", s.date),
group_by: day.d,
select: %{
  number_sales: count(s.id),
  total_value: sum(s.value),
  date: day.d
},
order_by: [asc: day.d]
  )
Repo.all(query)
|> Enum.map(fn entry -> Map.put(entry, :date, Date.from_erl!(entry.date)) end)
```

Comment: "I now changed the line ..." Can you post the modified code as well?

Comment: `on: v.contract_id == v.id` should be c.id, right? Fifth line

Comment: @LannyBose Right

Comment: Have the same issue. Do you managed to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
fragment("SELECT generate_series(?, current_date, '1 day')",
    type(c.inserted_at, :naive_datetime)
)
```

If you need more flexibility, like use `timestamptz`, you can change the `:datetime` to `:string`, change the `?` to `?::timestamptz` and send the value as string. Example:

```
fragment("SELECT generate_series(?::timestamptz, current_date, '1 day')",
  type(^"2017-01-01 00:00:00-01", :string)
)
```

The same goes for the interval:

```
fragment("SELECT generate_series(?, current_date, ?::interval)",
  type(^"2017-01-01 00:00:00-01", :string),
  type(^"1 day", :string)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Drawing on the answers above, here is a generalised solution for 'group by' queries of datetime values (datetime values are difficult for a 'group by' because they don't land on discrete points that match with the generate_series).
This solution generates series points even if there is no event data. Where event data is missing, use the coalesce() function to transform nil to 0.
Am using a table called Event with a field 'dt' (datetime), and field 'value' (integer).

```
  startpoint = startpoint = Timex.parse!("2011-04-18 12:00:00.000000Z", "{ISO:Extended}"
  group_span = 20     # group_by interval in minutes
  duration = 60       # in minutes, 24* 60 = 1 day, etc
  query = from(e in Event,
    right_join: minute in fragment(
      "select 
         ? + ( n    || ' minutes')::interval start_time,
         ? + ( n+?  || ' minutes')::interval end_time
      from generate_series(0, ?, ?) n", type(^startpoint, :naive_datetime), type(^startpoint, :naive_datetime), ^group_span, ^duration, ^group_span),
      on: e.dt >= minute.start_time and e.dt < minute.end_time,
    group_by: minute.start_time,
    order_by: [asc: minute.start_time],
    select: [minute.start_time, avg(e.value) ]
  )
```

Result

```
  [
    [~N[2011-04-18 12:00:00.000000], 3.0],
    [~N[2011-04-18 12:20:00.000000], 0.0],
    [~N[2011-04-18 12:40:00.000000], 0.0],
    [~N[2011-04-18 13:00:00.000000], 0.0]
  ]
```